# Could not execute julia chunks in Rmarkdown

Tags: julia, r-markdown

A minimal Rmd file is given  below

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "G. A"
date: ""
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(JuliaCall)
```


```{julia}
a = sqrt(2);  # the semicolon inhibits printing
println(a)
```
````

When compiled, I get the following error message:

`Julia version 1.5.0 at location C:\Users\g_ari\AppData\Local\JuliaCall\JuliaCall\julia\v1.5.0\bin will be used. Loading setup script for JuliaCall...`

Then Rstudio hangs!

I have been trying to resolve this problem.

Thanking in advance for a solution.

Comment: I have already installed `JuliaCall` package.

Comment: If this is the first time you use JuliaCall, it may need to do lots of settings in julia. The time it takes depends on the system, the internet, and lots of other things. The message you got is not error message, but a message showing the process of the JuliaCall setup. I suggest that you keep a separate session open while working on other things.

Comment: Thanks. I have been using materials available in web. I will come back with more inputs.